# Lost data when convert float to int in php

Tags: php, int

My code :

```
$baseprice=1705000/1.1;
var_dump($baseprice);
$parseprice=intval($baseprice);
var_dump($parseprice);
```

Result :

```
float(1550000) int(1549999)
```

As you can see, i lost 1 number when convert from float to int, where is it,what solution for this case for convert without lost data, Thanks.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is when caculate the float, I still dont know why they have different like bellow

```
$baseprice= 1705000/1.1 ; // 1550000

var_dump( decbin( $baseprice )); 
var_dump( decbin(1550000));
```

We can fix this by

```
$baseprice = round( $baseprice );
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using floating point numbers which will lose precision (see [this link](http://floating-point-gui.de/)).

If you are handling currency use integers and work in cents, pence, pfennigs, or whatever. Convert to a currency format just before display.

Answer (score 3):

The Solution would be as below

```
$baseprice=1705000/1.1;

var_dump($baseprice);

$parseprice=intval(ceil($baseprice));

var_dump($parseprice);
```

output:

> float(1550000) int(1550000)

Answer (score 1):

**Before float to integer round the value then you can convert to int**

```
$baseprice=1705000/1.1;

var_dump($baseprice);
//Before float to integer round the value then you can convert to int
$baseprice =round($baseprice);

$parseprice=intval($baseprice);
var_dump($parseprice);
```